# Passing a string parameter to a textblock

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to pass a string parameter from another xaml page (upon click of a button) into a content dialog and display it inside a textblock in another colour.

Example of the textblock text:

> Hey -parameter in red colour-, well -parameter in blue colour-, ... some text... -parameter in another colour-

My current method is to create several textblocks with different properties and then programmatically set the text to the corresponding textblock in the constructor.

There are too much redundant code and I believe there is a more elegant solution to this and I hope that someone could point me in the correct direction. Something tells me its binding but I am not sure how to proceed. (I'm new to XAML and trying to figure my way out by starting on something simple)

Comment: Can you provide some clarification? Is your dialog (a `Window` instance, maybe?) instantiated upon the button is clicked? Are there multiple parameters and colours you want to display in the dialog?

Comment: It is a content dialog in windows phone. It is similar to a normal XAML page where there are textblock tags. This content dialog is to be instantiated upon a button click from another xaml page. Yep, there are multiple parameters and in different colours to be displayed in the dialog via the textblocks. (I figure that I could just set the colours via textblock properties).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have an object set as the `ContentDialog.DataContext` and then use binding to achieve what you want.

In your `Button.Click` handler, set the data context:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    ContentDialog dialog = new ContentDialog
    {
        DataContext = new
        {
            RedText = "Red Colour",
            BlueText = "Blue Colour"
        }
    };

    dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

Then in the XAML of the `ContentDialog`, you can have something as:

```
<ContentDialog>
    <TextBlock>Hey <TextBlock Background="Red" Text="{Binding RedText}"/>, well <TextBlock Background="Blue" Text="{Binding BlueText}"/></TextBlock>
</ContentDialog>
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much! I guess the part I was looking for was the part on the passing of the Data Context!