# Send values from a Frame to a ContentDialog in a universal app

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Is it possible to send parameters values from a Frame to a `ContentDialog` in a universal app? This is how I call `ContentDialog` "MycontentDialog" from the MainPage :

```
private async void ConxBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await new MycontentDialog().ShowAsync();
}
```

Update:
I have used the "DataContext" like this:

```
bool stateConnexion=true;
    private async void ConxBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ContentDialog cd = new MycontentDialog();


                cd.DataContext = stateConnexion;

                    await cd.ShowAsync();  
        }
```

Now from `MycontentDialog` code behind, how can I access the `stateConnexion` value?

Update2:
I have used this reply [Passing a string parameter to a textblock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27193549/passing-a-string-parameter-to-a-textblock)

In my case like this:

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
bool stateConnexion=true;
        private async void ConxBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                ContentDialog cd = new MycontentDialog();
                 cd.DataContext = new
                {
                 testbool = stateConnexion
                };
                await cd.ShowAsync();  
            }
```

MycontentDialog.xaml.cs:

```
private bool testbool=false;

        public LocalisationPopUP()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

       private new void PrimaryButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            bool t = testbool;
          .....//traitment when I get value
        }
```

My problem now is that I get always a false value for the `testbool` variable

Any ideas please?

Comment: any help please :(

Comment: Why don't you just change your constructor to accept a parameter: ContentDialog cd = new MycontentDialog(stateConnexion) ?

Comment: thanks puzzler for your solution it works now :D